# Not able to pass the session value from view to controller while create login form in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

controller: Add_user.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
class Add_user extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct() 
    {
        parent :: __construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url', 'captcha', 'email'));
        $this->load->model('ads_data');
    }
    public function home()
    {
        $data['admin_id'] = $this->session->userdata('admin_id');
        print_r($data['admin_id']);
    }
}
```

view: login.php

```
<?php
    if($this->input->post('submit'))
    { 
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->db->select('username,password');
        $this->db->from('admin');
        $where = "username='$username' and password = '$password'";
        $this->db->where($where);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $num = $query->num_rows();
        if($num > 0)
        {
            $this->db->select('username,password,admin_id');
            $this->db->from('admin');
            $where = "username='$username' and password = '$password'";
            $this->db->where($where);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->result_array();
            $this->session->set_userdata('admin_id',$result);
            if($result == true)
            {
                redirect('add_user/home');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<p style='color: red;font-weight: 400;margin-right: 60px;'>Wrong email id or password! </p>";
        }
    }
?>
<form class="form-signin" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="username" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

In this code I have create a login form in my view where I want when I click on submit button it redirect me on add_user/home as I mention above the code and also pass the session value inside the controller but now I am unable to pass session value. It's working on localhost but not working on live. So, how can I print session value or pass to the controller?

From Comment

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files'; 
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session'; 
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200; 
$config['sess_save_path'] = BASEPATH . 'cache/'; 
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE; 
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300; 
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: Have you tried to set session config like sess_save_path, etc.. and permission for session folder?

Comment: Big no no if your are storeing plain passwords in database with out hashing them. If yo do hash them don't use MD5 it is out of date for passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Why have you added login code in your view when you are using CI. A preferred way will be to have action attribute of the form tag send the form data to your controller. Then you can perform validation as well as set the session variable.

```
<form method = 'post 'action = '<?php echo base_url()."/Controller/function"?>'
```